# Game Design favourite Plug-ins?

Tags: sound-design, sound-effects, monster, game-audio

I am searching for good plug-ins for mobile/tablet design. I have some Sound Toys plug-ins that i really like. 
I need some plug-ins that really alter the sound.

What do you guys use?

Thanks.

Comment: Volume control can really alter the sound. Does nuthin tonally but regards attenuation capabilities it's the bee's knees. Try and help yourself by being a little more objective.

Comment: Could you be more specific regarding the results you're after and what makes the plugin good for tablets/mobiles? Like Andy aka states any plugin would alter the sound - the question is if it is the kind of alteration you're looking for ;-)

Comment: Hello. My requests vary very much. I just need some Plug-ins that can change the sound in a way that the altered sound is unrecognisable form the original one.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

How about trying [SpectrumWorx](https://www.littleendian.com/consumers/spectrumworx/)?

Answer (score 1):

AudioThing MiniBit is capable of some realy nice oldschool 8-bit sounds. Maybe sonething to look into if you like that kind of sound.

This is a synth though